# How to denote that pipes on a remote machine end, and a pipe on the local machine follows

Tags: bash

I want to get some files from a remote machine. For this I make some pipes to determine which files have to be fetched, and these results I want to put in a pipe also.

The remote pipes combine to 1 command which is given to ssh.

I do not know how to let know where the pipes on the remote machine end and to put the results in the new local pipe. So I do:

```
ssh user@remote find ... | grep ...| awk ...| ls
```

The first 2 pipes are remote (find, grep , awk run on the remote machine), and the last pipe is local (ls runs on the local machine).

Comment: Are looking for this `ssh user@remote "find ... | grep ...| awk ..." | ls` (note the double quotes)? If not, please provide more details on your find, grep, awk command in order to get a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the part of the command you want to executed on remote machine into double quotes. E.g. `find`, `grep` and `awk` will be executed remote, while less will be exceuted local.

```
ssh user@remote "find ... | grep ...| awk ... "| less
```

As "tripleee" added in the comments it's better to use single quotes if there is no variable substitution in the quoted string. So use `"` if there is a variable inside the remote command.

```
ssh user@remote "find $foo | grep ...| awk ... "| less
```

or use `'` if there is no variable involved.

```
ssh user@remote 'find "foo" | grep ...| awk ... '| less
```

Comment: Single quotes are better unless you specifically require the shell to perform variable substitution in the quoted string. Double quotes may also be used as a slightly hacky workaround if the remote command line needs to contain embedded single quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll updated my answer corresponding to your advise.

Comment: I also found it out. In the remote commands, there are single quotes. So I used double quotes. But there was an exclamation sign. So I had to stop the "" string and put the ! between single quotes: "..."'!'"...". But there was also a dollar sign, which I escaped with a backslash \. I could not escape the exclamation sign with \. Maybe you know why.